# Converter predicados do java lambda

Tags: java, algoritmo, expressões-lambda

Estou tentando realizar uma transformação de modelo utilizando java lambda. Abaixo segue um bloco de código que exemplifica o que eu quero fazer:

```
public String translatePrimitivePredicate(){
    Predicate<Integer> predicate = a -> a == 1;     
    return translate(predicate) //"{$varA} === 1";
}
```

Assim, eu quero recuperar cada termo do predicado e utiliza-lo para executar uma lógica de negócio. Utilizando o exemplo acima, a conversão seria executada de maneira que o termo 'a' seria traduzido para uma String java "{$varA}", o operador lógico '==' para uma outra String java "===" e o valor '1' para "1". Assim, o retorno do método translatePrimitivePredicate seria a concatenação dos termos, como, "{$varA} === 1".

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

Pegar uma expressão lambda para tradução em tempo de execução é uma tarefa praticamente impossível(até agora), vou tentar te dar duas sugestões:

**1** - Pense em uma solução mais simples que não envolva uma tradução da forma que você descreveu;

**2** - Se você precisa mesmo fazer dessa forma, acredito que o [lambda-from-string](https://github.com/greenjoe/lambdaFromString) possa te ajudar com uma solução um pouco diferente(Function ao invés de Predicate).

Tentei simplificar o máximo que pude, mas mesmo assim ainda acho que não é uma solução muito interessante para produção(principalmente devido a performance).

**SOLUÇÃO**

Ao invés de tentar capturar a expressão lambda em tempo de execução podemos efetuar um **eval** de uma expressão(String) aplicando a tradução e convertendo a **String** em uma **Function**.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pl.joegreen</groupId>
    <artifactId>lambda-from-string</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Começamos definindo uma interface de tradução das expressões:

```
public interface FunctionTranslator<T> {

    void eval(String lambda, LambdaFactory factory) throws LambdaCreationException;

    T getFunction();

}
```

Implementação do tradutor de uma expressão que compara inteiros:

```
public class CompareIntegersFunctionTranslator implements FunctionTranslator<Function<Integer, Boolean>> {

    private final String TRANSLATOR_PATTERN = "{$var%s} === %s";
    private final TypeReference<Function<Integer, Boolean>> TYPE_REFERENCE = new TypeReference<Function<Integer,Boolean>>(){};

    private String translatedLambda;
    private Function<Integer, Boolean> function;

    @Override
    public void eval(String lambda, LambdaFactory factory) throws LambdaCreationException {
        this.function = factory.createLambda(lambda, TYPE_REFERENCE);       
        this.translatedLambda = translate(lambda);
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Integer, Boolean> getFunction() {
        return function;
    }

    private String translate(String expression) {
        String [] splited = expression.split("");
        return String
            .format(TRANSLATOR_PATTERN, 
                    splited[0].toUpperCase(), 
                    splited[splited.length - 1]);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return translatedLambda;
    }   

}
```

Implementação do tradutor de uma expressão que soma inteiros:

```
public class SumIntegersFunctionTranslator implements FunctionTranslator<Function<Integer, Integer>> {

    private final String TRANSLATOR_PATTERN = "{$var%s} += 1";
    private final TypeReference<Function<Integer, Integer>> TYPE_REFERENCE = new TypeReference<Function<Integer, Integer>>(){};

    private String translatedLambda;
    private Function<Integer, Integer> function;

    @Override
    public void eval(String lambda, LambdaFactory factory) throws LambdaCreationException {
        this.function = factory.createLambda(lambda, TYPE_REFERENCE);       
        this.translatedLambda = translate(lambda);      
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Integer, Integer> getFunction() {
        return function;
    }

    private String translate(String expression) {
        String [] splited = expression.split("");
        return String
            .format(TRANSLATOR_PATTERN, 
                    splited[0].toUpperCase(), 
                    splited[splited.length - 1]);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return translatedLambda;
    }   
}
```

Implementação de estratégia de tradução:

```
public enum FunctionTranslatorStrategy {

    COMPARE_INTEGERS(new CompareIntegersFunctionTranslator()),
    SUM_INTEGERS(new SumIntegersFunctionTranslator());

    FunctionTranslator<?> translator;

    FunctionTranslatorStrategy(FunctionTranslator<?> translator) {      
        this.translator = translator;
    }

    public FunctionTranslator<?> getFunctionTranslator() {
        return translator;
    }

}
```

Implementação de um translator factory:

```
public class FunctionFactory {

    private static final LambdaFactory LAMBDA_FACTORY = LambdaFactory.get();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> FunctionTranslator<T> create(
            String lambda, 
            FunctionTranslatorStrategy strategy) throws LambdaCreationException {

        FunctionTranslator<T> translator = (FunctionTranslator<T>) strategy.getFunctionTranslator();
        translator.eval(lambda, LAMBDA_FACTORY);

        return translator;      
    }

}
```

Testando:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LambdaCreationException {

    FunctionTranslator<Function<Integer, Boolean>> compare = FunctionFactory
            .create("a -> a == 1", 
                    FunctionTranslatorStrategy.COMPARE_INTEGERS);

    System.out.println(compare.toString());             // {$varA} === 1
    System.out.println(compare.getFunction().apply(1)); // true
    System.out.println(compare.getFunction().apply(2)); // false

    FunctionTranslator<Function<Integer, Integer>> sum = FunctionFactory
            .create("b -> b + 1",
                    FunctionTranslatorStrategy.SUM_INTEGERS);       

    System.out.println(sum.toString());             // {$varB} += 1
    System.out.println(sum.getFunction().apply(1)); // 2
    System.out.println(sum.getFunction().apply(2)); // 3
}
```

Note que existe código repetido e o método de tradução é bem básico(talvez regex pra melhorar). É possível melhorar bastante essa implementação e deixar as coisas mais simples, isso é só uma ideia de por onde seguir.